# How to map a datasource in DropList to a specific parameter on selection?

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a model that contains a parameter called `CssClassName` like this:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{51D5974A-7ABE-40C3-9EED-E32267C03112}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class Separator
    {
        public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string CssColorClass { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, from Sitecore side, this `CssColorClass` parameter is a `DropList` that points to a datasource where the template contains two parameters `ClassName` and `Description`. How can i tell the `CssColorClass` to "grab" the `ClassName` parameter and not the Item name of the items on the datasource?

On my razor view i have this:

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<MyModels.Models.Separator>
@using MyModels.Models
@using System.Web.Optimization
@{ 
    Separator separatorModel = GetRenderingParameters<Separator>();
}

@Styles.Render("~/bundles/separator-css")
<h2 id="@separatorModel.ID" class="separator @separatorModel.CssColorClass">@separatorModel.Title</h2>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **DropList** field only stores the name of the item selected.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you need to use a **Droplink** field instead.

The **Droplink** field will store the **ID** of the selected item.  From there, you can use the **ID** to find the selected item in Sitecore and convert it to a strongly-typed class that has the **ClassName** property that you are ultimately trying to retrieve.

Having said all of this above, looks like you're using **GlassMapper**.  If that's the case, it's even easier for you.  The type for your property that will map to the **Droplink** field should be the class that represents the item that will be selected in the **Droplink** field.  **GlassMapper** will automatically find the item in Sitecore by **ID** and cast it to the strongly-typed class for you.  If no item is selected in the field in Sitecore, **GlassMapper** will simply set the property to **null**.

Here's some sample code based on **GlassMapper**.

Let's say this is the class that represents the type of items that will be selected in the **Droplink** (I just made up a template ID):

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{12121212-1212-1212-1212-121212121212}", AutoMap = true)]
public class CssColor
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how you would update your **Separator** class:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{51D5974A-7ABE-40C3-9EED-E32267C03112}", AutoMap = true)]
public class Separator
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual CssColor CssColorClass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you put a sample using Glass.Mapper (that's what I'm using)

Comment: Code samples added, @Phoenix_uy.  Let me know if you need any further details.  Happy to help.

Comment: Thank you @Barbosa! that was the solution for me using Glass.Mapper

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be like this. I hate doing logic in the view, but maybe it will get you to where you need to be. You could also get the Droplink item with Glassmapper.

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<MyModels.Models.Separator>
@using MyModels.Models
@using System.Web.Optimization
@{ 
    Separator separatorModel = GetRenderingParameters<Separator>();
}

 @{
    var styleItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(separatorModel.CssColorClass);
    var cssClass = ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.LookupField) styleItem.Fields["ClassName"]).TargetItem["ClassName"];
  }

@Styles.Render("~/bundles/separator-css")
<h2 id="@separatorModel.ID" class="separator @cssClass">@separatorModel.Title</h2>
```